# R programming : Calling a R program I receive an error while using the png() function

Tags: r, linux

Below is the Linux Shell script used to call the Rscript.

```
#!/bin/bash

folder=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y-%R")
echo $folder
mkdir /home/nigel/Desktop/cron/"$folder"
Rscript /home/nigel/Desktop/cron/var.R $folder
```

And below is the Rscript

```
args<-commandArgs()
a<-args
print(args)

date_path=paste("/home/nigel/Desktop/cron/",a,"/file.png",sep = "")

#read the data and create the histogram, thens save it

data = read.csv("/home/nigel/Desktop/cron/Customer.csv", header = TRUE)
png(a,height = 1000,width = 1000)
hist(data$Age)
graphics.off()
print(date_path)
print("Ended well")
```

I receive the below error while executing the shell script.

```
(base) nigel@nigel:~/Desktop/cron$ ./var.sh
26-07-2020-12:10
[1] "/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R"                
[2] "--slave"                              
[3] "--no-restore"                         
[4] "--file=/home/nigel/Desktop/cron/var.R"
[5] "--args"                               
[6] "26-07-2020-12:10"                     
Error in plot.new() : could not open file '/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R'
Calls: hist -> hist.default -> plot -> plot.histogram -> plot.new
Execution halted
```

Please note that if I comment the below line of code from the Rscript I dont receive an error.

```
png(a,height = 1000,width = 1000)
hist(data$Age)
graphics.off()
```

I receive the error even when I replace graphics.off() by grap.off()

Comment: Have you tried `dev.off()`?

Comment: Try `commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)` to skip the first parameter being the R executable itself '/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `commandArgs` returns the name and path of the R executable.
It thus appears in the error message `/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R`.
This can be avoided via `commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)`.

I tested it in RStudio:

```
commandArgs()
# [1] "RStudio"       "--interactive"

commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
# character(0)
```

So the solution would be to use this line to get the png file name:

```
a = commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
```

Comment: Yes. changing {args<-commandArgs() } to {args<-commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)} resolved the problem